# How can I merge two or more text files and remove duplicate email addresses with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, merge, duplicates

I have two text files with space delimited email addresses - newalias.txt and origalias.txt. Essentially these are email alias mappings I want to merge together, but there are duplicates in the first index. I want to favor the line with a match in the first index in newalias.txt and drop the dup in origalias.txt. Also, drop exact duplicates.

```
OrigAlias:

    sam@example.com sam.smith@example.root.org
    jane@example.com jane.maiden@example.root.org
    bob@example.com robert.johnson@example.root.org

NewAlias:

    sam@example.com samuel.smith@example.root.org
    jane@example.com jane.married@example.root.org
    bob@example.com robert.johnson@example.root.org

Results:

    sam@example.com samuel.smith@example.root.org
    jane@example.com jane.married@example.root.org
    bob@example.com robert.johnson@example.root.org
```

I've been studying Python recently and I've done some interesting things, but text parsing is still a challenge for me. I'm still getting familiar with the options in Python.

### Edit

I worked on the problem by myself for a while and came up with this:

```
# Py 3.4.1
# Instructions:
# Rename current domain mapping export to dmapsOrig.txt
# Rename whitespace delimited customer modifications file to dmapsNew.txt
# Place the two text files and this script in the same directory
# Run the script: 'python dmapsMerge.py'

from datetime import date

OrigDict = {}       # Create empty dictionaries for processing
NewAddDict = {}     #
ResultsDict = {}    #

with open('dmapsOrig.txt', 'r') as file1:       # Populate OrigDict dictionary from dmapsOrig.txt file
    for x in file1:
        if not x.startswith("#"):               # Ignore commented lines
            dmaps = x.split()
            OrigDict[(dmaps[0])] = ''.join(dmaps[1])

with open('dmapsNew.txt', 'r') as file2:        # Populate NewAddDict dictionary from dmapsNew.txt file
    for y in file2:
        if not y.startswith("#"):               # Ignore commented lines
            newdmaps = y.split()
            NewAddDict[(newdmaps[0])] = ''.join(newdmaps[1])

with open('dmapsOrig-formatted-%s.txt' % date.today(), 'wt') as file3:
    file3.write('## Generated on %s' % date.today() + '\n') # Insert date stamp
    for alias in sorted(OrigDict.keys()):
        file3.write(alias + ' ' + OrigDict[alias] + '\n')   # Format original input and write to sorted file

ResultsDict = OrigDict.copy()   # Copy OrigDict dictionary keys and values to ResultsDict Dictionary
ResultsDict.update(NewAddDict)  # Merge new dmaps into original

with open('dmapsResults-%s.txt' % date.today(), 'wt') as file4:
    file4.write('## Generated on %s' % date.today() + '\n')     # Insert date stamp
    for alias in sorted(ResultsDict.keys()):
        file4.write(alias + ' ' + ResultsDict[alias] + '\n')    # Format dictionary output and write to results.txt file

file1.close() # Close open files
file2.close() #
file3.close() #
file4.close() #
```

Comment: Before we answer have you thought how it could be done? Suitable containers that only allow unique values?

Comment: Yeah, I quickly arrived at the conclusion that it needed to be dictionary based, but it took me a while to sort out the details. I doubt my solution was as elegant as it could be, but I'm still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your files are not too big, the simplest solution would be to load `origalias.txt` in memory, then load `newalias.txt` (updating existing entries if necessary), and dump the merged data.

```
aliases = {}
with open("origalias.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val = line.strip().split(" ")
        aliases[key] = val
with open("newalias.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val = line.strip().split(" ")
        aliases[key] = val
with open("mergedalias.txt", "w") as f:
    for key, val in aliases.items():
        f.write("{} {}\n".format(key, val))
```

A few keys to the code above:

- Using a dict `aliases` allows you to prevent duplicates, as setting a new value for a key replaces the old value.
- Files are iterable (i.e. usable with `for`), each iteration applies to one line, which is convenient in your scenario.
- `.strip()` removes leading and trailing spaces; then .split(" ") cuts the string according to spaces, and the two components are affected to `key` and `val` respectively.
- Note that if a line contains less or more than two space-separated parts, the affectation to `key, val` will raise an exception. Consider using `.split(" ", 1)` for a more tolerant behaviour.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The solution above assumes that your are not interested in preserving the order of the source files... Indeed, dicts store pairs with no particular order.

Answer (score 2):

```
# construct a dictionary from orig file
original_dict = dict([tuple(i.split(' ')) for i in open('origalias.txt')])
# create a new dictionary and update the original dictionary(this overwrite new values for same key)
original_dict.update(dict([tuple(i.split(' ')) for i in open('newalias.txt')])))

# now write to new file if you want
fp = open('newfile','w')
for key, value in original_dict.iteritems():
    fp.write('%s %s\n'%(key, value))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('origalias.txt') as forig, open('newalias.txt') as fnew, open('results.txt', 'w') as fresult:
    dd = {}
    for fn in (forig, fnew): # first pass will load with original, then overwrite with new
        for ln in fn:
            alias, address = ln.split(' ')
            dd[alias] = address

    # just write out all element in dictionary
    for alias, address in dd.iteritems():
         fresult.write('%s %s\n' % (alias, address))
```